# Pass argument to `$ref` in OpenAPI 3

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-3.0

Assume I have following schema to reuse later using `$ref`:

```
"schemas": {
      "Order": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "integer",
            "format": "int64"
          },
          "petId": {
            "type": "integer",
            "format": "int64"
          }
        }
      }
```

But I have another schema similar to this:

```
"schemas": {
      "Order": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "integer",
            "format": "int64"
          },
          "itemId": {
            "type": "integer",
            "format": "int64"
          }
        }
      }
```

Only difference between them is `itemId` and `petId`, I want to create only one schema and pass `itemId` or `petId` when referencing.
How to accomplish this? Are there any alternative solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no way to pass arguments along a schema reference, really.

What we could do in your case is to have a base `Order` schema with just the common properties, and then separate schemas for `petId`/`itemId` `Order`s that utilize [`allOf`](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/combining.html#allof).

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57466914/1763012) for another example (or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29470366/1763012) for a more concrete one!).

Comment: Yeah, it seems you are right. I think this feature should be added. I had the same problem with [json schemas](https://json-schema.org/)