# how to use same component schemas using $ref which vary a little?

Tags: openapi, swagger-editor

I am trying to re-use component schemas as reference which vary based on their usage.

I have a "Employee Model" that will contain say below items:-
EmployeeID and EmployeeName

So I have created a component schema in YAML like below:-

```yaml
components:
    schemas:
        Employee:
            type: object
            properties:
                EmployeeID:
                    type: integer
                EmployeeName:
                    type: string
                EmployeeAge:
                    type: integer
```

Now I want to use this in multiple paths like

1. Use this in both request and response body, but with the caveat that
   in the request I should only take in the ID and response can hold
   all.
2. Use this in the response body but only with Name and Age
3. Use this in a request body with only Name

Can you please recommend the best approach to use $ref and achieve the above?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combining defintions in Swagger docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29463634/combining-defintions-in-swagger-docs)

Answer (score 0):

Check the JSON Schema docs on [combining schemas](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/combining.html); in this particular case you'd use `allOf`, for example.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29470366/1763012) a related answer.